# Dynamic CSS loading

Tags: css, angular

i have 2 styles 
Style1.scss and Style2.scss

**Style1**

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

@import "assets/css/aos/styles.css";
@import "assets/css/aos/aos.css";

@import "assets/css/layout.css";
@import "assets/css/theme-brand-1.css";
```

some css files and one theme file

**Style2**

some css files and one theme file like style 1

The theme file is different.

Based on the url param for example `http:\\localhost:4000\login?section=x`
i need to load style 1 and for other  `http:\\localhost:4000\login?section=y` need to load style2.

## Method-1 - not worked

**Component**

```
this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.param1 = params.brand;
    switch(params.brand){
      case 'x': this.cssUrl = '/src/styles1.scss';
      break;
      case 'y': this.cssUrl = '/src/styles2.scss';
      break;
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" [href]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl)'>
```

Comment: hii @Akshaya, what is your question here ? are you getting an error or what? it seems ok to me

Comment: No error, and the href gets proper value but its not loading.The css in angular.json is working whatever i added additionally not working. @kushalshah

Comment: look at this link https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/ i think it's same as which you are doing

Comment: This i have done but not working

Comment: the link only work for .css (and they need been in "assets/folder"). I think that the only way is "compile" yours styles1.scss and styles2.scss. the other thing you can try is "prepend" your .scss with, e.g. .content1 and .content2 and include the two .scss in the Angular app, after a [ngClass]="'content1'" or [ngClass]="content2" make the trick

Comment: check this:https://juristr.com/blog/2019/08/dynamically-load-css-angular-cli/

Answer (score 0):

Create a canonical link dynamically using directive and move the link to head declaration in directive load

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMoveToHead]'
})
export class MoveToHeadDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, 
              private elRef: ElementRef, 
              @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, this.elRef.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'appmovetohead');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.renderer.removeChild(this.document.head, this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
canonicalLink:string;
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
//In oninit or when your data is ready, generate canonical link
ngOnInit() {

       let canLink = "styles1.scss"; // set style here based on your condition
       // You can use pipe for sanitizing but lets do it here
       this.canonicalLink = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(canLink);

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="canonicalLink">
  <link  rel="canonical" appMoveToHead [attr.href]="canonicalLink" />
</div>
```